# Android app crashes after permission set: Ionic capacitor

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

Here i have simple ionic app followed by [this tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/using-the-capacitor-filesystem-api-to-store-photos/) , and it works well, but when i run the android application for the first time and once i trying to access `FileSystem` or `Camera` functionalities, app asks for the permission and once i gave the permission application crashes with `Unfortunately, app has stopped.` message. And after that it works fine.

**Updated**

It happened with Android API level 23, and once i tried with API level 27 and 29 it works fine.

`variables.gradle`

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 29
    targetSdkVersion = 29
    ...
 }
```

And i' using latest versions of both Ionic and Capacitor.

Whats happening here ?